# WIndows Phone 8.1 Calendar Events reading issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, calendar, windows-phone

I need to read calendar events from windows phone 8.1 . I implemented code using below link.But Phone hangs when i call the functionality. I add two events in calendar manually so i need to fetch those events.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286421(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_AccessingCalendarData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can  you  elaborate your  issue...

Please  select  necessary  Capabilities..so  that  Windows phone  SDK  allows  your  app  to  use  required  functionality..

ADD

```
ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS  
ID_CAP_IDENTITYDEVICE
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
```

check the  checkbox  next  to  them

[image: Follow this image]

Build  again  and see  if  problem persists,if  persists . revert  back  with  error  screen

Answer (score 0):

I did not select  ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS  in WMAppManifest  file..

I resolved the issue using above correction